# Insert form data on a sheet and check if it is full and create another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a way that every time I fill out the form the data that I've choose comes to the sheet (image below) and when it has 5 answers it creates another sheet and insert the nexts answers on the next sheet.
One of the problems I had was that when I fill out the form the function "for" inserts the same answer in the 5 lines,moreover, I couldn't find a way to create each sheet through this "for" that inserts the data. Somebody to help me?[image]

```
function SendToSheet(url, Title){
for(var i=8; i<=24;i=i+4){
if(getSheet.getRange("B"+i).isBlank()){
    getSheet.getRange("B"+i).setValue('=hyperlink('+url+'";'+Title+')')
  }else{
      getSheet.getRange("B"+i).setValue('=hyperlink('+url+'";'+Title+')')  
  }}}
```

Comment: Do you have 5 quesstions on every form

Answer (score 2):

Create Sheet for each form submission and inserts questions and answers and a checkboxes for each question.

Using an installable trigger.

```
function despositAnswers(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let aA=e.values;
  const ash=ss.insertSheet(aA.shift());//insert sheet named with timestamp
  const lsh=e.range.getSheet();
  let hA=lsh.getRange(1,2,1,lsh.getLastColumn()-1).getValues()[0];
  aA.forEach(function(a,i){
    ash.getRange((i+12)+(i*4),1,2,1).setValues([[hA[i]],[aA[i]]]);//insert questions and answers
    ash.getRange((i+12)+(i*4),2).insertCheckboxes();//insert checkboxes
  });
}
```

Typical Event Object:

```
{"authMode":"FULL","namedValues":{"Question5":["5"],"Question4":["4"],"Question2":["2"],"Timestamp":["6/12/2020 18:15:02"],"Question3":["3"],"Question1":[""]},"range":{"columnEnd":6,"columnStart":1,"rowEnd":7,"rowStart":7},"source":{},"triggerUid":"5688318963244367705","values":["6/12/2020 18:15:02","","2","3","4","5"]}
```